# Jmeter: send image and other parameters together in post request

Tags: performance, automation, jmeter

I am testing an api. I need to upload image with api key. I can upload image separately but I can't post image and api key together.

```html
{
  "apikey" : "12345kjl",
  "image" : ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, I was able to upload image from postman. I used jmeter to record the script form postman and use exact recorded configuration in jmeter script.
I send "apikey" from Parameters section and image from "File Upload".
I didn't add header manager.
Actually content-type in header manager was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your server implementation, in some cases you need to post a [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded image, in this case you can use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) and [__base64Encode()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) functions combination like:

```
{
  "apikey" : "12345kjl",
  "image" : "${__base64Encode(${__FileToString(/path/to/the/file,,)},)}"
}
```

Another option is building a multipart post request manually so it will look like:

```
--boundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8



JSON Metadata
--boundary
Content-Type: file MIME type



File content
--boundary--
```

See [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) article for step-by-step instructions on implementing it.

In general you should capture "real" request using a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) and configure JMeter in order to send the same request (apart from dynamic parameters)

Comment: I tried using the first method but the response shows as "no image provided" but however I can successfully upload an image using postman. The headers shown in postman are as follows:
cache-control →private
content-encoding →gzip
content-length →193
content-type →application/json; charset=utf-8
date →Thu, 11 Jan 2018 22:28:46 GMT
server →Microsoft-IIS/10.0
vary →Accept-Encoding
x-aspnet-version →4.0.30319
x-aspnetmvc-version →5.2
x-powered-by →ASP.NET